# How do I start a bitcoind server in deprecated mode for multiple functions

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

I have a bitcoind server running bitcoin-core **version 0.17**. Now since I need to use deprecated RPC methods I need to start the bitcoind server in deprecated mode, so I am already able to run it to support the accounts rpc methods by running the following command

```
bitcoind -deprecatedrpc=accounts
```

However, I found that `signrawtransaction` has also been deprecated, so I ran the bitcoind server with the following command :

```
bitcoind -deprecatedrpc=accounts,signrawtransaction
```

The server started successfully, however I was still getting this error :

```
"signrawtransaction is deprecated and will be fully removed in v0.18. To use signrawtransaction in v0.17, restart bitcoind with -deprecatedrpc=signrawtransaction.\nProjects should transition to using signrawtransactionwithkey and signrawtransactionwithwallet before upgrading to v0.18"
```

So I started the server again with the following command :

```
bitcoind -deprecatedrpc=signrawtransaction
```

And this time the transaction went through, however I need to start the bitcoind server to support both the deprecated methods. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the two flags independently.

ie, `-debug=bench -debug=net`